# How to edit and Update Checkbox values in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in larval and I want to edit and update checkbox values. Now I can able to store checkbox values, but when I click edit it's not showing checked values in edit view. So please help me how can I resolve this solution. Here I will give you my code.

**My Blade File**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="readbooks" value="Readbooks" {{ $users->hobbies=="Readbooks"? 'checked':'' }}>Readbooks
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="music"  value="Music"{{ $users->hobbies=="Music"? 'checked':'' }}/> Music
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="games" value="Games" {{ $users->hobbies=="Games"? 'checked':'' }}/> Games
```

**My controller File**

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);
    echo $users;
    return view('edit',['users'=>$users]);
}
 public function updateUser(Request $request, $id)
{ 
    User::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);
    return redirect("view")->withSuccess('User! Successfully Updated!');
}
```

Comment: I need to fetch checkbox values in edit view before update

Comment: ``$users->hobbies`` is an array if I am not wrong and you're simply comparing with a single string word which is failing the condition. You should use ``in_array("Music",  $users->hobbies)`` instead of ``users->hobbies=="Music"`` and so on.

Comment: @OMiShah now that you mention it, it can be! And if that a comma seperated string you can use since php8 `str_contains($users->hobbies, 'Music')`. But only Karthika knows what it is ..!? ;-)

Comment: You mean like this? {{ in_array("Music",  $users->hobbies)? 'checked':'' }}/> Music

Comment: @Karthika yeah........ if it is an array.

Comment: @MaikLowrey, hmmm yeah xD

Comment: I tried this but I am getting error "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given"

Comment: @Karthika how you're storing the values in the database? datatype? or format ?

Comment: @Karthika  `dd($user->hobbies)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to give the hobbies as array back to the view and then check if the value of the input is in the array of hobbies:

First return the user to the view:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);

    return view('edit', [
        'users' => $users,
        'hobbies' => explode(',', $user->hobbies)
    ]);
}

public function updateUser(Request $request, $id)
{ 
    User::find($id)->update($request->all());

    return redirect("view")->withSuccess('User Successfully Updated!');
}
```

Then in your view

```
<form action="{{ url('updateText/'.$users->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="readbooks" value="Readbooks" {{ in_array('Readbooks', $hobbies) ? 'checked' : '' }}>Readbooks
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="music" value="Music" {{ in_array('Music', $hobbies) ? 'checked' : '' }}>Music
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" id="games" value="Games" {{ in_array('Games', $hobbies) ? 'checked' : '' }}>Games
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting route error Undefined variable: users This line sowing error <form action="{{ url('updateText/'.$users->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >

Comment: @Karthika yeah, the variable is `$user`, because you are fetching one user

Comment: I am not getting clearly. Getting little bit confused

Comment: I've updated my answer with the <form> tag, just check how the $user variable is spelled. Use the singular word of user. I think this will help you

Comment: If i change user I will affect other fields

Comment: even i have  changed users to user i am getting error in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to keep using `$users`, then you need to return this in your edit method in the controller: `return view('edit', ['user' => $user, 'hobbies' => explode(',', $user->hobbies)]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239206/discussion-between-dennis-and-karthika).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have looks fine. but as @OMiShah correctly pointed out, the values may have been stored in an array or in a comma-separated string in the database. since we don't know this now, two possibilities to build the condition:

`in_array("Music",  $users->hobbies)`

**or**

`str_contains($users->hobbies, 'Music')`

Comment: I tried like this {{ str_contains($users->hobbies, 'Music')  }} but nothing response

Comment: @Karthika okay. Can you show us what  dd($user->hobbies)` printed?